# Android Failed to remove Item in Listview with custom layout

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to do a Add / Remove item with EditText and Button in Listview.

After keying some text in EditText and click the button, this new item will be added below. When clicking the item, it will be remove.

**It works fine with**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>

(Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
```

Here is the coding.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String get_text=editText.getText().toString();
        arrayList.add(get_text);
        final ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        editText.setText("");

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                arrayList.remove(position);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**However, it doesn't work if I change to Custom layout for the Listview. When clicking on the item, it doesn't remove and also no error prompts**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>

(Main.this,R.layout.row,R.id.textView,arrayList);
```

[image]

Comment: your code is wrong

Comment: Every time you click on button and reset  the new Adapter to listview

Comment: anonymous is write, why you include listview.setonItemClickListener inside buton's click event?

Comment: @DivyangPanchal , it doesn't work even I changed to Anoymous coding. it doesn't work for custom layout. It only works for "simple_list_item_1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have made change in your code. Try this. **:)**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 String get_text=editText.getText().toString();
 arrayList.add(get_text);
 editText.setText("");
 arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
    });

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                    arrayList.remove(position);
                    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hey, it's not working. Please take note, for custom layout, it's (Main.this,R.layout.row,R.id.textView,arrayList);   not (Main.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList) . It doesn't work for custom layout

Comment: Have you created custom Adapter?

Comment: no... but I thought since i can add item, i should be able to delete it as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124043/discussion-between-anonymous-and-gosulove).